# is there something like AAsset_closeFileDescriptor in android ndk?

Tags: android, android-ndk

as far as I know, file descriptor should be closed once opened.

According to documentation of Asset of Android NDK, (https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset),

there is nothing like `AAsset_closeFileDescriptor` even though you can find and use `AAsset_openFileDescriptor`.

Was I wrong?? Is it ok if, after `AAsset_openFileDescriptor` is used, you leave it as it is until program ends ???

Answer (score 0):

You must call `close()` for the opened file descriptor.

Comment: File descriptors are not pure NDK entities, they are unix compatible file descriptors. You need them when you want to pass opened assets into libraries which can work only with unix file descriptors. close() is proper way to close a file descriptor. Why do you need other options?